# Set focus for python turtle textinput

Tags: python, focus, turtle-graphics, textinput

In my python project (game) I have a function to get player (2) names:

```
def get_names(self):
    self.lp_name = turtle.textinput("Left Player", "Enter your Name")
    self.rp_name = turtle.textinput("Right Player", "Enter your Name")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PP4sM.png)

For the first (Left Player) the textinput field is active - has focus but NOT for the second (Right Player)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tested this on my system and it works fine, please provide details about the environment under which you're running this code.

Comment: It's Windows 10, Home, x64; Python 3.10.0

Answer (score 0):

The textinput field is not active because the focus shifts from the Main Window to the popup window when you click 'OK'.
*(try clicking on the main window and you can see the textinput field becoming active.)*

So you could use a `screen.tracer()` function to update the main screen after each input.

sample would be like :

```
screen = turtle.Screen()

def get_names(self):

    self.lp_name = turtle.textinput("Left Player", "Enter your Name")

    screen.tracer(1) #Refreshes the turtle window and sets focus to the main window.

    self.rp_name = turtle.textinput("Right Player", "Enter your Name")
```

This should work.